# How to save file into the home partition in Arch

Tags: arch-linux, partition, fdisk, partition-table

I have recently noticed that Arch saves files in  the root partition, although I create a home partition too. I use fdisk to partition the disk and these are the exact commands I type in it:
[image]

After partitioning both two, I type:

[image]

How can I tell Arch to save files in the home partition, instead of using the root one?

EDIT:

Sorry if I am using a really bad language to describe this problem, but I’ve been into Linux since like two weeks or so. Please, be patient.

UPDATE:

This is the image of the content inside /etc/fastab:

[image]

This is obtained by the command:

```
genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Just like the installation guide suggest to do.

Comment: What do you mean by *"log into /home"*?

Comment: I meant how am I able to store files and stuff like that in the home partition, instead of the root one?

Comment: Add a record for `/home` to `/etc/fstab`. That's it. You may want to transfer `/home` from your root to your real home partition. Mount both and use `cp -a src dst`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I’ll be trying that later.

Comment: @deomanu01 Please get yourself an overview of the (un-)related words. What does *log in*, *mount*, *store*, *partition*, *directory* and *file system* mean - I think if you know this then it is easier to get your mind structured.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. Though it seems a bit unclear what the problem is. What do you mean by _"Arch saves files in the root partition, although I create a home partition too"_? What files are you referring to? What are you expecting the system to do instead?

Comment: I mean that if I install a program, it will get the space from the root partition, instead of the home one and I would like to solve this, making it to get the space from the home partition. Is it possible?

Comment: Everything is possible but, as pointed out [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608609/how-to-log-into-home-partition-in-arch#comment1135884_608620), it is not how things are meant to work on a *nix system.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it looks like you are mounting the partitions from the live image, which will not persist once you reboot into the installed system. As others have mentioned, you need to add an entry to your `/etc/fstab` (see [fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab)) in order to have the "home" partition auto mounted to `/home`.

When you log in as a non-root user, if your working directory is `/`, then it may be the case that your user does not have a home directory. You can set one using:

```
# usermod -d /my/new/home -m username
```

(See [Users and groups – Change a user's login name or home directory](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_groups#Change_a_user%27s_login_name_or_home_directory)
in the ArchWiki.)

Comment: In the images I posted, I only show those parts because I thought were the most important to show, but after installing the base packages with pacstrap /mnt, I also generate the fstab with genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab. Is this what you were talking about? As I was able to understand, I did this partially wrong, meaning that I need to type: genfstab -U /mnt/home >> /mnt/etc/fstab. Is this correct?

Comment: I think that is what you want. Can you post the contents of /mnt/etc/fstab? You should have an entry for both /  and /home

Comment: Check the post, I took a photo of “cat /etc/fstab”.

Comment: It looks to me like it is working as expected. What is the output of `lsblk` when run from the installed system (not the live image)?

Comment: It is /dev/sda divided into two partitions, just like it should be. The problem is that if I try to install some program, it gets the space of the root partition, instead of the home one.

Comment: Oh, that’s because packages generally don’t place any files in /home. The root partition is *for* distribution software. Executables, libraries, documentation, system-wide config files, etc. have specific places in the Linux file system hierarchy (see https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages//man7/file-hierarchy.7.html). You can always mount these on different devices or partitions if you want to, for example, mount different directories with different options (e.g. noexec to prevent files from being executed)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Didn’t know this :). Thanks again.